# Is there a faster then $O(n^2)$ multiplication algorithm that is faster for smaller numbers then long multiplication and feasable to do by hand?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms, asymptotics, arithmetic

I know karatsuba and faster multiplication exist, but they aren't faster then grade school multiplication for small numbers, and often have high overhead so they are infeasible to do by hand in most cases. Is there a faster then $O(n^2)$ multiplication algorithm that is reasonable to do by hand and faster then long multiplication for small n?

Comment: For small $n$, why is it important to be faster than $O(n^2)$?

Comment: Just curious honestly. This could be useful for doing multiplication by hand. Note by small i mean like >10 digits(that would take on the order of 100 multiplications with an O(n^2) algorithm) digit numbers in base 10

Comment: There is a technique I have sometimes used for multiplication of more than a few digits, but few enough to do by hand. Take one of the numbers that is to be multiplied and work out the multiples of that number by each of the digits in the other number using mostly addition rather than multiplication. For example, to get $2x$ you add $x$ to itself (although doubling is usually easy enough), to get $4x$ you add $2x$ to itself, to get $7x$ you add $2x$ to $5x$, etc. There are also particular tricks for multiplication by certain digits that can help, such as how to compute $5x.$

Comment: Once you have all the necessary one-digit multiples of one of the numbers, you just need to copy them into the places where you write the intermediate steps of long multiplication.